# Akka Streams with Scala 3: mapAsync fails

Tags: scala, akka-stream, scala-3

I made some first experiments with Akka Streams and Scala 3. Although I know that Akka has only experimental support for Scala 3, I am a little bit surprised that the following simple program does not work:

```scala
object HelloAkka extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem();
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val done = Source(1 to 5)
    .mapAsync(2)(n => Future {
      println(s"processing item $n in thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId}")
    })
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)

  Await.result(done, Duration.Inf)
  println("stream processing finished.")
  Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
  println("main thread terminated.")
}
```

When I build this program with Scala 3.2.0 using the following `build.sbt` the program hangs when `mapAsync` is invoked (no future is ever executed):

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.2.0"  // fails
// ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8" // works

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello-akka",
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.20"
  )
```

When changing the Scala version to 2.13.8 the program behaves as expected. Also version 2.7.0-M1 of the Akka Streams library shows the same behavior.

Since `mapAsync` is elementary to Akka Streams programming, I suspect that I miss an obvious error.

Full running example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jheinzel/PHzMfGNDSmaSbssTX5YhWw.

Comment: Not sure why, but: it seems like the `Future` never completes. It does work when you change the ExecutionContext to `implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global`. And it (kind of obviously) also works if you use `Future.successful`(because that synchronous).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you're encountering weirdness with `extends App` which relies on `DelayedInit` being treated specially by the compiler.  Scala 3 no longer gives `DelayedInit` special treatment, instead the code in the body of `HelloAkka` becomes part of the static initializer of the object, which means it executes before the `HelloAkka` object is considered to be a real object by the JVM.  This means that any thread outside the thread initializing `HelloAkka` (i.e. the equivalent of the "main thread") will block until such time as the initializing thread completes, which in this case entails a deadlock thanks to the `Await`s in the body of `HelloAkka`.

[Moving your code into a `main` method (which is not typically necessary with Scastie) causes your program to run as expected](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/64EG5H4RTsW0rBbpPnmYOQ).

[Removing the `Await`s to allow the static initializer to return causes the program to run as expected](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TbWEqwiqQg2ldK8ZEDie0w)

`Await`ing in an `App` which is intended to be compiled for Scala 3 will deadlock if some asynchronous task (in this case the Akka Stream's `mapAsync` stage) reads a `val`/`var` from the `App`.

The [Scala 3 docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html) recommend either [`@main` annotations or an explicit `def main`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html).

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/htAyPFVVRxi9HqoS8EXDKg <- note that the deadlock occurs when scheduling the future in `mapAsync`