# Scala: Why does using a variable inside a new thread result in a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, scala, deadlock, scala-3

Suppose I have the following piece of code which starts two threads. Every thread prints its work and a parameter needed for the work:

```scala
object ThreadingDeadlock extends App {
  val jobs = List("foo", "bar")
  val parameter = "Param"

  val threads = jobs
    .map(job => {
      new Thread(() => {
        println(s"Thread started for job $job")
        println(s"Parameter: $parameter")
      })
    })

  threads.foreach(t => t.start())
  threads.foreach(t => t.join())

  println("Done!")
}
```

This is the output of the program. Note there is no "Done!" at the end (-> the program does not terminate):

```
Thread started for job foo
Thread started for job bar
```

When I comment out `println(s"Parameter: $parameter")` it works correctly and the program terminates. So the problem can be solved when capturing the parameter from the outer scope in a local variable inside the `.map` function:

```
...

val threads = jobs
  .map(job => {
    val param = parameter

    new Thread(() => {
      println(s"Thread started for job $job")
      println(s"Parameter: $param")
    })
  })

...
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
Thread started for job foo
Parameter: Param
Thread started for job bar
Parameter: Param
Done!
```

---

Why does this program never terminate (-> result in a deadlock) when I use the parameter inside the thread?

What implicit magic does Scala/the JVM do?

I am using Scala 3.2

Comment: What is your Scala version? Works fine on 2.10, 2.11, 2.12, 2.13! https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nyL4ND2STBiVwVMprByGxw (You can change scala versions in build settings)

Comment: Why do you keep insisting in using raw threads?

Comment: I am using scala 3.2

Comment: @luis-miguel-mejía-suárez I am not limited to raw threads but want to know the technical details why this problem occurs.

Comment: Try not `extend`ing `App`, but using a main method.  Scala 3 has different behavior from Scala 2 and no longer treats `App` specially.

Comment: Using a main method works as expected

Answer (score 3):

As Levi pointed out in the comments, the problem comes from extending `App`. The solution is to use a `main` function. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764947/4563449)  provides more details.

The working program would look like this:

```scala
object MyApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jobs = List("foo", "bar")
    val parameter = "Param"

    val threads = jobs
      .map(job => {
        new Thread(() => {
          println(s"Thread started for job $job")
          println(s"Parameter: $parameter")
        })
      })

    threads.foreach(t => t.start())
    threads.foreach(t => t.join())

    println("Done!")
  }
}
```