# Why `final` required in this Future-style concurrent programming in Scala?

Tags: scala, promise, future, final

I have a question about the use of the `final` related with Fiture-style concurrent programming.  Thank you for your time.

I have a simple Future-style concurrent program, which spawns many Futures, prints out the value of the last Future, and exits.  When the constant value  used in the body of the Futures is declared with `final val` the program works as I expected.  However when I omit `final` it blocks.  I would like to understand the role of the `final` in this example.

The following is my program.

I expect it prints out 10, 20, ..., 300, and finally `Futures done`, and exits.  It runs fine but when I replace the `final val` declarations with `val`, it seems to block indefinitely.

```scala
object Futures extends App {
  final val TICK_MS = 10
  final val N_TICKS = 300
  
  def doPrint(num: Int, p: Promise[String]): Future[Int] = {
    val f = Future {
      blocking { Thread.sleep(TICK_MS) }
      if num > N_TICKS then p.success("Futures done.")
      num + 1
    }
    if num % 10 == 0 then println(num)
    for v <- f do doPrint(v, p)
    f
  }

  val p = Promise[String]()
  doPrint(0, p)

  p.future.onComplete {
    case Success(v) => println(v)
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
  }

  Await.ready(p.future, Duration.Inf)
}
```

---

### My environment

- sbt.version: 1.8.2
- scalaVersion: 3.2.2
- JVM: zulu19.32.15
- macOS Venture 13.3, Apple M1, 16GB

Comment: Can reproduce blocking in Scala 3: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/YzDDv31HQe6HgWRXZCnoMg (final, no blocking), https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/YzDDv31HQe6HgWRXZCnoMg/1 (not final, blocking), but not in Scala 2: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/YzDDv31HQe6HgWRXZCnoMg/2 (final, no blocking), https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/YzDDv31HQe6HgWRXZCnoMg/3 (not final, no blocking).

Comment: Don't use `App`, use a proper `main` method instead, `App` has some weird behaviours related to initialization.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks for pointing out the Scala version.  The following is my environment:

- sbt.version: 1.8.2

- scalaVersion: 3.2.2

- JVM: zulu19.32.15

- macOS Venture 13.3, Apple M1, 16GB

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you.  By converting the App object to a standard one with `@main` method, a class definition with `/* final */ val` declaration now works.  Possibly deadlock between instance initialization code and the `App` constructor?

Comment: If removing `App` helps then probably the issue is what the code is rewritten into. Without looking at the bytecode I would guess that probably the issue is circular initialization dependency in classloader caused by some lambda used to initialize these values when they are not `final`. (`object`'s constructor uses a lambda to initialize `val`, lambda is defined in object so classloader needs object's construction to finish to run the lambda, Classloader gets deadlocked. It happens also in Java programs when they use lambdas for initialization of static fields).

Comment: Or, maybe a "normal" deadlock, since object initialization was synchronized in Scala 2, not sure about Scala 3. But maybe this flag https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/safe-initialization.html would tell you something about the issue.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762457/akka-streams-with-scala-3-mapasync-fails... TL;DR: Scala 3 changes the semantics of `App` around initialization to be a static initializer like any other class, around which the JVM standard requires a lock.  By making the variables final (and since no other code references it), the compiler is able to inline the references so there's no deadlock.  It's strongly recommended in Scala 3 to not use `App`, especially if concurrency is involved.